# C# - Library for creating XML editor based on XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, intellisense

So I am planing to make XML editor module that is capable of instant validating with XSD and displaying IntelliSense at current editing position.

The validation part is simple but I have problems creating IntelliSense.

Is out there any library that makes this IntelliSense simple or is there no other way then writing this from scratch?

Comment: I need something very simple. For example: 
Load(xml,xsd) 
AvailableElements(currentElement,insertPosition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using Visual Studio (Express, even)? It has XML Intellisense built in.

Comment: Including schema validation built in!

Comment: Well I don't need an application that can do this. I need to make my own module for my own application. That's why I said I need a library/class...

Comment: @Gapi: Visual Studio is extremely extensible. In particular, you can create applications based on Visual Studio. See the [Visual Studio 2010 SDK](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25622469-19d8-4959-8e5c-4025d1c9183d). In particular, look at the Visual Studio Shell. Every time you've used Visual Studio, you've used this ability to build on top of the Visual Studio Shell. That's what Microsoft does to create the packages you buy off the shelf.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/diy-intellisense.aspx

Should give you a good head-start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .NET Class: [XmlSchemaValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidator.aspx)

The 2 key methods are: GetExpectedParticles and GetExpectedAttributes that return an XmlSchemaObject. Before you use these you need to setup the context for the validator by validating all preceding and ancestor elements and attributes.

You will also need to use methods on the classes derived from XmlSchemaObject, these expose the various parts of the post-compile Schema Object Model. The model hierarchy itelf closely resembles the XML structure that you will find in XSD files. You will probably need to use recursion and there are quite a few potential traps, for example when handling substitution groups, but a reasonable solution can be completed in around 2000 lines of c#.

Comment: Great, only problem is that Silverlight doesn't have this class =)

Comment: Ok, I tested this class. It doesn't work as I exacted. With this class I can only get expected elements based on current hierarchy of validator object(XSD) and not based on created XML file.

Comment: You would need to get the node path to the caret position in the XML, then iterate through the nodes to set up the validator object context first - before the GetExpectedParticles call. Even after that, you need to convert the expected particle, depending on type, XSD is non-trivial, hence 2000 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Actipro's SyntaxEditor](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/). It's available for WinForms, WPF, and Silverlight and includes support for abstract syntax tree construction, common IntelliSense-like visual cues etc.

Answer (score 0):

We are using [SyntaxBox](http://code.google.com/p/alsing/wiki/SyntaxBox) in one of our projects. Performance isn't *that* good, there are commercial products out there that are also rather inexpensive and of high quality.

In addition, I believe [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) is the most powerful free syntax-coloring editor component out there.